# Introducing a value in javascript to radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, input, radio-button, output

I want my radio buttons to be checked according to the sign of the number that the user gives as an input. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function func1(x, y){

    var z = x + y
    document.getElementById("Z").innerHTML = z;
    var Sign1
    if (z < 0) {

        Sign1 = "pos";
    }
    else {

        Sign1 = "neg";
    }
}                           

</script>
<form >
first input:<br>
<input id="Y" type="text" y="Y" value=85>
<br>
second input:<br>
<input id="X" type="text" x="X" value=15>
<br> 
The Answer:<br>
<input id="Z" type="text" z="Z" > 
 <br>
<input type="radio" name="sign" value="pos" checked> positive
<input type="radio" name="sign" value="neg"> negative

<br><br>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="func1(parseInt(document.getElementById('X').value),parseInt(document.getElementById('Y').value))">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here according to the value of z. How should I introduce this value and the condition in javascript code the radio buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var func1 = function (){
   var x, y, z;
   x= Number(document.getElementById("X").value);
   y= Number(document.getElementById("Y").value);
   z= x + y;
   
   document.getElementById("Z").value =  z;
    
    if (z < 0) {
  document.getElementById("neg").checked=true;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("pos").checked=true;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>
<form>
first input:<br>
<input id="Y" type="text" value=85>
<br>
second input:<br>
<input id="X" type="text" value=15>
<br> 
The Answer:<br>
<input id="Z" type="text" > 

<input type="radio" name="sign" id="pos"> positive
<input type="radio" name="sign" id="neg"> negative
<br>

<button type="button" onclick="func1()">Try it</button>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to the end of your function:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("sign");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].checked = elements[i].value === Sign1;
}
```

This loops through all DOM elements with name "sign"--in your case these are all your radio buttons. If the `value` of the radio button matches your `Sign1` variable, then check the radio button, otherwise mark it as unchecked.

I think your logical check for `pos` vs. `neg` is reversed, but I'm not sure about your exact intentions. You can see a runnable example in the snippet below.

```js
function func1(x, y){

    var z = x + y
    document.getElementById("Z").innerHTML = z;
    var Sign1;
    if (z < 0) {

        Sign1 = "pos";
    }
    else {

        Sign1 = "neg";
    }
  
  var elements = document.getElementsByName("sign");
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].checked = elements[i].value === Sign1;
  }
}
```

```html
<form >
first input:<br>
<input id="Y" type="text" y="Y" value=85>
<br>
second input:<br>
<input id="X" type="text" x="X" value=15>
<br> 
The Answer:<br>
<input id="Z" type="text" z="Z" > 
 <br>
<input type="radio" name="sign" value="pos" checked> positive
<input type="radio" name="sign" value="neg"> negative

<br><br>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="func1(parseInt(document.getElementById('X').value),parseInt(document.getElementById('Y').value))">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but would you please explain a little bit about that for loop?